# How to pass ViewModel data to JavaScript file?

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I got a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` in my controller , and I have a js file in **/wwwroot/view-resources**, so How to pass the Dictionary to js file

I have try `var result = '@Model.Dic'` ,and I got a string-type variable @Model.Dic,

I also have try to use a hidden input with `value="@{@Model.EditList}"`, and I got a result

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]
```

I use abp with .netcore

Answer (score 1):

1. Serialize the dictionary into a JSON string in C#.
2. Parse the JSON string in JavaScript.

```html
// View.cshtml

using Newtonsoft.Json;

<script>
var jsonString = '@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Dic)';
var dictionary = JSON.parse(jsonString);

console.log(dictionary);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm sorry to reply late，I have try the code, but I got a string `"@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Dic)"`, it seems that My description is not accurate enough, my javascript code is not in view.cshtml, It is a external file

Comment: by the way, I  have got the data with an action in controller and  an ajax function in js file,  but if there is any way to pass ViewModel data to external javascript file, I really want to konw it

Comment: You can't do that and probably shouldn't. JS files are likely cached. What are you trying to achieve? You probably have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).